# Orient text to face the user when the model is rotated

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is there any event that I can use to detect when the camera (or model) is rotated to orient a text to face the user?

Right now I'm using the last line of this code to face the text, but I need to do it every time the camera changes.

```
let geom = new THREE.TextGeometry("blaaaa", {
                    font: "monaco",
                    text: "arial",
                    size: 10,
                    height: 0,
                    curveSegments: 3,
                  });

geom.computeBoundingBox();
var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFF00FF});


mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);


mesh.position.x = result.geomVertex.x;
mesh.position.y = result.geomVertex.y;
mesh.position.z = result.geomVertex.z;
                

mesh.quaternion.copy(this.viewer.getCamera().quaternion);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT, (e) => {
   console.log(e)
})
```